# how to set different minimum order amount for free shipping for different user roles in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set different minimum order price for different user roles for free shipping.

How can I implement it?

I am currently using the below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 'filter_woocommerce_available_shipping_methods');
```

`filter_woocommerce_available_shipping_methods()` function:

```
function filter_woocommerce_available_shipping_methods( $methods ) {

    global $woocommerce;
            get_currentuserinfo();
            global $current_user;
             $roles = $current_user->roles[0];
            if($roles == '')
                {
                    $roles = 'subscriber';
                }

    $shippingrate = new WC_Shipping_Rate();

    $shippingrate->id = 'free_shipping';

    $shippingrate->label = 'Kostenloser Versand';

    $shippingrate->cost = '0';

    $shippingrate->method_id = 'free_shipping';

     if ( $roles == 'corporate' && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= 50   )  {
      unset($methods);
      $methods = array();
      $methods['free_shipping'] = $shippingrate;
    }

   else if ( ( $roles == 'retail' && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= 80 ) || ( $roles == 'gastronomy' && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= 80) ) {
      unset($methods);
      $methods = array();
      $methods['free_shipping'] = $shippingrate;
    }

    else if( $roles == 'distributor' && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= 400 )  {
      unset($methods);
      $methods = array();
      $methods['free_shipping'] = $shippingrate;
    }

    else if( $roles == 'distributor' && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= 400 )  {
      unset($methods);
      $methods = array();
      $methods['free_shipping'] = $shippingrate;
    }

    else if( $roles == 'subscriber' && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= 45 )  {
      unset($methods);
      $methods = array();
      $methods['free_shipping'] = $shippingrate;
    }

    return $methods;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a plugin for this? I've created a plugin that can be configured with conditions, including based on user role.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-advanced-free-shipping/